# Cant open new elastic beanstock site 'Connection timeout'

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, ssl, asp.net-mvc-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my MVC 5 web application to aws elastic beanstock through visual studio 2017. I used the extension and clicked through all of the defaults. I see in my beanstock terminal that the application health is green. when I click the provided url i get a timeout error in my browser.

My first guess was to check to make SSL was working (my IIS config file in visual studio requires SSL. So I tried to attatch a certificate to the provided URL in amazon but got an error. Under the 'In Use' column it says no.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do your security looks like for the instances and the ELB? Is your ELB in a public subnet?

Comment: Ive been doing some digging and it seems like it has something to do with SSL. I disabled SSL for my app and was able to get a web page back. I might take down, you dont know how to add SSL to a single instance beanstock app do you?

Comment: Are you terminating SSL at the ELB or do you want to go thru to the instance? Sounds like you want it to go thru to the instance.

Comment: It appears from aws load balancers page that I don't have any. So, I think the preferred option is to go thru to the instance. My project is quite simple, its just an mvc app that you log into, the app passes your credentials to an on premises exchange server in order to get emails and stuff.

Comment: In an answer I added the docs on how to do that.

Comment: The resources you provided aren't that clear. the links dont really outline useful steps that are on my skill level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153271/discussion-between-strongjz-and-david-bell).

Comment: Okay thanks - will join!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to configure your elb to do tcp pass thru and terminate ssl at the instance http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-tcp-passthrough.html

If you want to move to using ACM and terminating SSL at the ELB here is the documentation to do that 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html